# Scroll-wheel TOGGLES to "zoom" on desktop and chrome

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, firefox, browser, scrolling

Sometimes my mouse decides to ***toggle*** scroll-is-now-zoom mode. I then need to restart the machine. It's happened around 3-6 times in the last couple of months.

**Affected areas:**

- Desktop (zooming bulks and shrinks desktop icons)
- Chrome (0-to-100% zoom)
- NOT Firefox (it still scrolls normally)

**Demonstration:**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCe-BUFVcY8

**My environemnt:**

- Chrome: 39.0.2171.95 (stable)
- Firefox: 34.0 (stable)
- Mouse: Razer E-3lue Blue 2.4GHz 2500 DPI LED Wireless Optical Gaming Game Mouse

[image: **enter image description here**]

**Prior Research:**

From reading several other SU posts, insights:

- One post mentions he/she uses both firefox and chrome (so do I) (see below)
- It always seems to involve Chrome (all posts below).

**SE:**

- Duplicate question but solution fails:

  - [chrome-zooms-in-when-scrolling-up-and-out-when-scrolling-down](https://superuser.com/questions/712567/chrome-zooms-in-when-scrolling-up-and-out-when-scrolling-down)

    - A: "Are all of you using a program called KatMouse or WizMouse?" - No
- Nearly duplicate but "intermittent" as opposed to "toggle" behaviour:

  - [Mouse wheel scroll causes zoom in/out in Google Chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/706168/mouse-wheel-scroll-causes-zoom-in-out-in-google-chrome)
- Related:

  - [disable-ctrlmouse-wheel-zooming-in-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/243127/disable-ctrlmouse-wheel-zooming-in-chrome)

**Out-of-SE:**

Tried to post it in google forums, failed to post, got very frustrated and ended up on a half-day tangent posting a load of other complaints I had there.

Comment: Ok, did you check by any chance your keyboard 'Ctrl' button is pressed when use your mouse scroll button. By pressing 'Ctrl' key in the keyboard behaves like this in my machine.

Comment: no.. I have two keyboards and tried experimenting with plugging them both, one in one out.